# Task.Wait for async method passes during application startup while it causes deadlock in WPF button handler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

The behavior of `Task.Wait()` is unexpectedly different depending on the "environment" where invoked.
Calling `Task.Wait()` during application startup with below async method `TestAsync` passes (doesn't cause a deadlock) while the same code blocks when called from within a WPF Button handler.

Steps to reproduce:
In Visual Studio, using the wizard, create a vanilla WPF .NET framework application (e.g. named `WpfApp`).
In the `App.xaml.cs` file of the app file paste below `Main` method and `TestAsync` method.
In the project properties set `Startup object` to `WpfApp.App`.
In the properties of `App.xaml` switch `Build Action` from `ApplicationDefinition` to `Page`.

```cs
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task<DateTime> task = App.TestAsync();
            task.Wait();

            App app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            return app.Run();
        }

        internal static async Task<DateTime> TestAsync()
        {
            DateTime completed = await Task.Run<DateTime>(() => {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return DateTime.Now;
            });
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(completed);
            return completed;
        }
    }
```

Observe that the application starts properly (after 3sec delay) and that the "completed" `DateTime` is written to debug output.
Next create a Button in `MainWindow.xaml` with `Click` handler `Button_Click` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```cs
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ...

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task<DateTime> task = App.TestAsync();
            task.Wait();
        }
    }
```

Observe that after clicking the `Button`, the application is deadlocked.

Why can't it pass in both cases?
Is there a way to change invocation (e.g. using ConfigureAwait at the correct task or somehow setting SynchronizationContext or whatever) so that it behaves identical in both invocations, but still synchronously waits for completion?

### Update on limitations of the solution.

The async method like TestAsync comes from a library that cannot be changed.
The invocation code of the TestAsync method is nested within a callstack that cannot be changed either, and the code outside the callstck makes use of the returned value of the async method.
Ultimately the solution code has to convert the async method to run synchronous by not changing the method nor the caller.
This works well within UT code (NUnit) and during application startup, but no more within a handler of WPF.
Why?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), go [async all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way).

Comment: @Stephen Cleary - I can understand if You are fed up with answering ever the same simple questions. My understanding of the spirit of stackoverflow is not to delegate to lengthy second sources, but to give an answer on the point here.
Why is there different behavior during startup and in WPF handler?

Comment: *"Is there a way to change invocation [...] so that it behaves identical in both invocations"* -- Are you interested in a solution that ensures a consistent deadlock in both situations?

Comment: @RolandSchneider: I'm not fed up at all. Sometimes I don't have time to post a full answer but I can toss out some resources that will help you figure it out. The key for the difference in this case is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, which is not set until the app enters its main UI loop.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary - Seems I was tired and hungry yesterday and not as polite as should be. Thanks for the hint regarding `SynchronizationContext`. I wasn't aware that execution during startup automatically uses a `ThreadPool` thread for continuation.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias - Of course async methods within a library should behave consistent. Out of curiosity I would be interested to see how to make it blocking, but would not (and can not) use it here. One recommendation I saw regarding library code was to make use of ConfigureAwait(false) when possible so that the thread is defined within the library - as also suggested by TJ Rockefeller below (1.)

Comment: @Roland I am not attempting to suggest a solution before it's clear to me what exactly is the problem. If the problem is that the first `task.Wait();` doesn't deadlock, in other words if deadlocking is the desirable behavior, then just ask and we will find a solution to that. Please update the question and clarify if consistent deadlocking is the behavior that you are looking for.

Comment: There is, by design no satisfying possibility to avoid the deadlock in WPF, see also Stephen Cleary's discussion below and with link to [Async Programming - Brownfield Async Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development).  
Accepted answer is [option 2. from TJ Rockefeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71619387) which is equivalent to [Thread Pool Hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-thread-pool-hack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways that you can handle this situation, but ultimately the reason there is a deadlock in one situation and not the other is that when called in the Main method `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null, so there isn't a main UI context to capture and all async callbacks are handled on thread pool threads. When called from the button, there is a synchronization context which is captured automatically, so all async callbacks in that situation are handled on the main UI thread which is causing the deadlock. In general the only way you won't get that deadlock is by forcing the async code to not capture the synchronization context, or use async all the way up and don't synchronously wait from the main UI context.

1. you can `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside of your `TestAsync` method so that it doesn't capture the synchronization context and try to continue on the main UI thread (this is ultimately what is causing your deadlock because you are calling `task.Wait()` on the UI thread which is blocking the UI thread, and you have `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(completed);` that is trying to be scheduled back onto the UI thread because await automatically captures the synchronization context)

```cs
DateTime completed = await Task.Run<DateTime>(() => {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return DateTime.Now;
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

2. You can start the async task on a background thread so that there isn't a synchronization context to capture.

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => App.TestAsync());
    var dateTime = task.Result;
}
```

3. you can use async up the whole stack

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task<DateTime> task = App.TestAsync();
    var dateTime = await task;
}
```

4. Given how you are using it, if you don't *have* to wait until the task is done, you can just let it go and it will finish eventually, but you lose the context to handle any exceptions

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //assigning to a variable indicates to the compiler that you
    //know the application will continue on without checking if
    //the task is finished. If you aren't using the variable, you
    //can use the throw away special character _
    _ = App.TestAsync();
}
```

These options are not in any particular order, and actually, best practice would probably be #3. `async void` is allowed specifically for cases like this where you want to handle a callback event asynchronously.

Comment: @TF Rockefeller - I'm not asking how to implement async stuff in general, there are lots of sources out there. The question is about a specific point where I didn't yet find information about. Maybe I haven't explained the limitations, see update on question.

Comment: @RolandSchneider I added some clarification as to why the deadlock happens in one scenario, but not the other which is really just explaining what Stephen Cleary said in one of his comments.

Comment: Nice, but why block the `ThreadPool` thread by calling `.Result`? You could just remove the `.Result`, and have the same effect without blocking a thread: `Task.Run(() => App.TestAsync());`. The `Task.Run` understands async delegates.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias good point, I removed the `.Result` from the background thread call.

Comment: @TJ Rockefeller - Thanks for the explanations. The SynchronizationContext.Current == null during startup is obviously the difference and causes that the `WriteLine(completed)` continuation in `TestAsync` is executed in a `ThreadPool` thread, I didn't see this at first.
Unless there is a spectacular solution answer for the topic within the next few days, I nominate this as the correct answer.

Comment: @TJ Rockefeller - Option 2. is most practicable in the use case at hand, the async `TestAsync` (which is only a model for more complex functionality) has demonstrated during startup/in console application/NUnit that its continuation code runs well in `ThreadPool` threads without a need to route back to WPF thread.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, in .NET many of the front ends have a single UI thread, and therefore must be written async all the way through. Other threads are reserved and utilized for things like rendering.

For WPF, this is why use of the `Dispatcher` and how you queue up work items is important, as this is your way to interact with the one thread you have at your disposal. More reading on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/threading-model?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Ditch the `.Result` as this will block, rewrite the method as async, and call it from within the `Dispatch.Invoke()` and it should run as intended

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't it pass in both cases?

The difference is the presence of a `SynchronizationContext`. All threads start out without a `SynchronizationContext`. UI applications have a special UI thread(s) and at some point they need to create a `SynchronizationContext` and install it on that thread(s). Exactly *when* this happens isn't documented (or consistent), but it has to be installed at the point the UI main loop starts.

In this case, WPF will install it (at the latest) within the call to `Application.Run`. All user invocations from the UI framework (e.g., event handlers) happen within this context.

The blocking code deadlocks with the context because this is the [classic deadlock situation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), which requires three components:

1. A context that only allows one thread at a time.
2. An asynchronous method that captures that context.
3. A method also running in that context that blocks waiting for that asynchronous method.

Before the WPF code installed the context, condition (1) wasn't met, and that's why it didn't deadlock.

> Is there a way to change invocation (e.g. using ConfigureAwait at the correct task or somehow setting SynchronizationContext or whatever) so that it behaves identical in both invocations, but still synchronously waits for completion?

We-ell...

This is a rephrasing of "how do I block on asynchronous code", and there's no good answer for that. The *best* answer is to *not* block on asynchronous code at all; i.e., use [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way). Especially since this is *GUI code*, I'd say for the sake of UX you really want to avoid blocking. Since you're on WPF, you may find a technique like [asynchronous MVVM data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding) useful.

That said, there are a few [hacks you can use if you must](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development). Using `ConfigureAwait` is one possible solution, but not one I recommend; you'd have to apply it to all `await`s within the transitive closure of all methods being blocked on (Blocking Hack). Or you can shunt the work to the thread pool (`Task.Run`) and block on that (Thread Pool Hack). Or you can [remove the `SynchronizationContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/8a73d0467d40ca41f9f9cf827c7a35702243abb8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/SynchronizationContextSwitcher.cs#L36-L56) - unless the code being blocked on manipulates UI elements or bound data. Or there are even *more* dangerous hacks that I really can't recommend at all (Nested Message Loop Hack).

But even after putting in all the work for a hack, you'll still end up blocking the UI. The hacks are hard precisely because they're not recommended. It's quite a bit of work to give your users a *worse* experience. The far, far better solution (for your users *and* future code maintainers) is to go async all the way.

Comment: Thanks, got the message. By design there is no satisfying possibility to avoid the deadlock in WPF.
For the situation discussed here (async function from library which runs well during startup/in console application/NUnit) probably option 2. from TJ Rockefeller above is most practicable.
It equals what you describe as "Thread Pool Hack" in MSDN Magazine "Async Programming - Brownfield Async Development".
Routing back to the WPF `Dispatcher` seems not necessary, usage of the async method without WPF demonstrates that its continuation code runs well in `ThreadPool` threads.