# RTSP Stream not receiving frames

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, rtsp, frames

I am trying to use RTSPClientSharp (https://github.com/BogdanovKirill/RtspClientSharp) to receive an RTSP stream (currently testing with rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4) in which the uri works with any other RTSP stream tester I try. In my application it never receives a frame and gets stuck using "rtspClient.ConnectAsync().Wait".

```
Uri RTSPURL = new Uri("rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mp4");
                            CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
                            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
                            var connectionParameters = new ConnectionParameters(RTSPURL, credentials);
                            connectionParameters.RtpTransport = RtpTransportProtocol.TCP;

                            using (var rtspClient = new RtspClient(connectionParameters))
                            {
                                rtspClient.ConnectAsync(token).Wait();
                                rtspClient.ReceiveAsync(token).Wait();
                                Console.WriteLine("Using RTSPClient");
                                
                                rtspClient.FrameReceived += (sender, frame) =>
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Got Frame");
                                    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(frame.FrameSegment.Array, 0, frame.FrameSegment.Array.Count(), true))
                                    {
                                        
                                        bmp = new Bitmap(memStream);
                                    }
                                    
                                };
                            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm not receiving any errors so I haven't tried much. Also if I remove the .Wait following the Async functions it doesn't receive any frames.

Comment: Calling `Wait()` blocks the UI thread. You have to `await` the async methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71619155/1136211, https://stackoverflow.com/q/10065000/1136211

Comment: If you can't get it to work, consider trying the free evaluation of [LEADTOOLS Multimedia Suite SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/products/multimedia-suite). The SDK lets you play the video by assigning the url string "rtsp://…" to the [`PlayCtrl.SourceFile property`](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/multimedia/to/source-filename-syntax.html). You can similarly save the video to disk using the same syntax with `ConvertCtrl.SourceFile`. There are also countless features in the SDK for video processing, recompression, restreaming, etc. Disclosure: I work for the SDK's vendor.